# CORS Policy works with some networks

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cors

I created an API in node JS (https://exemple.com/postRequest) on my domain, and a React App (https://exemple.vercel.app for exemple). On my private network (Home) everything is working, my React app fetch the API url with a Post REQUEST, and it's working. But, at work, it's not working anymore, I have this message :

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myapi.com/postRequest' from origin 'http://exemple.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

For test, I use nodeJs Cors on my express app to allow ALL. And it's working when I am home

```
app.use(cors())
```

Both are on server, and I don't know why my connection impact the post REQUEST ? Do you have information and/or a way to fix it ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Hey, I recommend you to testing your API using Postman. You can input the API URL and payload, then attempt to make a request from Postman. If Postman returns a response, it indicates that your server is configured correctly. However, if it doesn't, there might be an issue with the server configuration. Please inform me of the response you receive in Postman and I will try to help you :)

Comment: @MaulikPatel I use tools like postman, and everything is working fine with it !

Comment: @MaulikPatel Found the solution. My web server has security and block some IP if they have bad reputation etc.. I disabled it and it works !

Answer (score 1):

The reason it works at home but not at work is most likely due to changes in network configurations or security of the network.

To resolve this issue, setup your Node.js Express server to include the necessary CORS headers to accept requests from your React app's domain. Rather than permitting all origins, you can specify the allowed origins in the CORS middleware.

This is what i think will work

```
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://exemple.vercel.app',
  // origin: ['https://exemple.vercel.app', 'https://another-domain.com'],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

you can add multiple origin inside the array

Comment: Thank you for the help ! I try this right now and tell you if everything is working !

Comment: The error is still there. Here is the messages :

`net::ERR_FAILED 307 (Temporary Redirect)`

`TypeError: Failed to fetch`

And still the same cors message

Comment: I need to mention that GET request is working, just the POST request is not. I can fetch data and use it, but I can't post anything to my server using post